# how to read from a file & save the content into a linked list?

Tags: java, file-io, linked-list

I'm trying to write the code for a program that saves the content of a txt file into a singly linked list, every line in the txt file represent an object. I used Scanner to read from the file but I don't know how to get the words in the list.

any tip or hint is highly appreciated.

my attempt: 
class Item

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
private String name;
private double price;

public Item() {
name="" ; 
price=0.00 ;
}

public Item(String n, double p) {
name = n ; 
price = p ;
}

public void setName(String n) {
name = n ;
}

public void setPrice(double p) { price = p ;
}

public String getName() { 
return name ; 
}

public double getPrice() {
return price ;
}
}
```

class Node

```
public class Node {
public Item data ;
public Node next ;

public Node(Item d) {
    data = d ;
}

public Node(Item d, Node n) {
    data = d ; 
    next = n ; 
}

public String toString() {
    return data+"";
}
}
```

class ListItems

```
public class ListItems {

private Node first;

public ListItems(){
    first=null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first==null;
}

public void addAnItems(Item d, int i){
    Node node1=new Node(d);
    node1.next=first;
    first=items.get(i);
}

public void displayList(){
    Node current = first;

        while(current != null){
        System.out.println(current.toString());
        current=current.next;
        }
}
}
```

class FileItems

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.* ;

public class FileItems {
public static void main (String[]args){
Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in) ;
        try {
        Scanner input2=new Scanner(new File("items.txt")) ;
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR OPENING FILE") ;
        System.Exit(1) ;
        }

        while (input2.hasNext()){
        String name1=input2.next() ;
        double price1=input2.nextDouble() ;
        }

            ListItems items=new ListItems();
                System.out.println("CHOOSE ONE OF THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS :") ;
                System.out.println("ENTER 1 TO ADD AN ITEM TO THE LIST") ;
                System.out.println("ENTER 2 TO DELETE AN ITEM FROM THE LIST") ;
                System.out.println("ENTER 3 TO DISPLAY ALL THE ITEMS IN THE LIST") ;
                System.out.println("ENTER 4 TO CLOSE THE PROGRAM") ;

                int in=input1.nextInt() ;

                        switch (in) {
                        case 1 : case1() ; 
                            break ;
                        case 2 : case1() ;
                            break ;
                        case 3 : displayList() ;
                            break ;
                        case 4 : System.Exit(1) ;
                            break ;
                        }

                        public void case1() {
                            System.out.println("ENTER THE NAME OF THE ITEM, THE PRICE AND THE INDEX ");

                            try {
                            System.out.println("NAME: ") ; 
                                String n2=input1.next() ; 
                            System.out.println("PRICE: ") ;
                                double p2=input1.nextDouble() ;
                            System.out.println("INDEX: ") ; 
                                int index=input1.nextInt() ;
                            }

                            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                            System.out.print("INVALID INPUT") ;
                            }

                        Item I=new Item(n2, p2) ;
                        addAnItem(I, index) ;
                        }

                        public static case2() {
                            System.out.println("ENTER THE INDEX OF THE ITEM TO DELETE IT ") ;

                            try {
                            int index=input1.nextInt() ;
                            }

                            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                            System.out.print("INVALID INPUT") ;
                            }
                        items.remove(index) ;
                        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have to use you're own list?

Comment: No I don't have to, I can use class List.

Comment: Your code style is terrible.  So terrible that it hurts my brain to try to read it!  If you want other people to read your code, you MUST pay attention to code style.

Comment: I'm still new at java. I tried to make my code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

> any tip or hint is highly appreciated

Here are some tips:

- Indent your code properly.
- Don't put closing curly brackets after semicolons like that.
- Class names should start with a capital letter: `listItems` and `fileItems` are wrong.

If you don't have a recommended style guide, use the standard Java one - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html